# Can multiple Django `bulk_update` queries be part of single atomic transaction?

Tags: python, mysql, django, transactions, bulkupdate

Can multiple Django `bulk_update` queries be part of a single atomic transaction?

Usually when we want to save multiple models in single atomic transaction we can do something like this:

```py
def my_update(model_a, model_b, model_c, model_d):
    with transaction.atomic():
        model_a.save()
        model_b.save()
        model_c.save()
        model_d.save()
```

Similarly I want to update a bulk set of models in single atomic transaction, like so:

```py
def my_bulk_update(models_a, fields_a, models_b, fields_b, models_c, fields_c, models_d, fields_d):
    with transaction.atomic():
        Model_A.objects.bulk_update(objs=models_a, fields=fields_a)
        Model_B.objects.bulk_update(objs=models_b, fields=fields_b)
        Model_C.objects.bulk_update(objs=models_c, fields=fields_c)
        Model_D.objects.bulk_update(objs=models_d, fields=fields_d)
```

Digging around the `bulk_update` code I found the following snippet:

```
        with transaction.atomic(using=self.db, savepoint=False):
            for pks, update_kwargs in updates:
                rows_updated += self.filter(pk__in=pks).update(**update_kwargs)
```

It shows the updates are done within an atomic transaction. It means the `my_bulk_update` has nested atomic transaction and I'm not aware what the behaviour would be. So some queries I have regarding this are:

1. Is `my_bulk_update` atomic?
2. What is the behaviour of the nested transaction?
3. Could the `using=self.db` mean that nested transactions be ignored?